# How to install fonts with Nix in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, nix

If I try something like

```
nix-env --install nixpkgs.fira-code
```

the package will be installed but the font will not be available anywhere.

How do I install fonts and make them available for use in Ubuntu using Nix?

Comment: Depends a lot on your setup ... you're using `nix` as a user running in Ubuntu? Then you probably need to add a path from your profile (with the fonts) to whatever font search path you're using.

Comment: @DanielJour can you add an example of how that would be done? My set up is exactly as you described (using Nix as a user running in Ubuntu).

Answer (score 8):

I had the same question, and [asked it](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/how-to-install-fonts-on-a-non-nixos-system/14758) in the NixOS Discourse. The solution is to manually add Nix's font directory to the user's fontconfig (as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283783/adding-a-new-per-user-font-directory)), like this:

- Create the local fontconfig directory:

  ```sh
  $ mkdir -p ~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/
  ```
- Create a file in that directory (called, for example, `10-nix-fonts.conf`) specifying where to locate the Nix fonts:

  ```xml
  <?xml version='1.0'?>
  <!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
  <fontconfig>
    <dir>~/.nix-profile/share/fonts/</dir>
  </fontconfig>
  ```